# TypeWriter - Filter classes or properties without a given attribute

Tags: typescript, typewriter

Using a Typewriter .tst file it is possible to only include Properties with a certain attribute using a `$Properties([MyAttr])` filter.

Like this for example:

```
export class $Name{
        $Properties([MyAttr])[
        public $name: $Type = $Type[$Default];]
    }
```

**Is it possible to include all properties *except* those with the given attribute?**

Something like this maybe:

```
export class $Name{
        $Properties(![TsIgnore])[               //but this doesnt work!!
        public $name: $Type = $Type[$Default];]
    }
```

I've tried what I can think of `![TsIgnore]`, `[!TsIgnore]`, etc. but none work. Also cannot find anything in the [docs](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/)

Comment: The simplest way I know of is using Lambda expression inside of the filter. E.g. `$Properties(p => !p.Attributes.Any (...))[...]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I implement an `IsIncluded` method:

```
bool IsIncluded(Class c)
{
    // exclude attributes
    if(c.BaseClass?.FullName == "System.Attribute") return false;

    return !ExcludeObjects.Any(ec => c.Name == ec || c.FullName == ec);
}
```

and somewhere at the top, I have this:

```
static string[] ExcludeObjects = new string[]
{
    "MyClassToExclude",
    "Full.Namespace.Path.To.MyOtherClassToExclude",
};
```

and the template has this:

```
$Classes($IsIncluded)[ ... ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
  bool IsIncluded(Property c)
  {
      if(c.Attributes.Any(a => String.Equals(a.name, "TypeScriptExportExlude", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        return false;
      return true;
  }
```

where "TypeScriptExportExlude" is the attribute on your property that you want to exclude.